# Flask - Function instead of data in MySQL database

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask App with WTForms, handling data entry. There is a `SelectField` that properly shows the data that I have in the `erga` table. However, when using the form, instead of adding the right values to the `ergo` column to the database table, the app adds functions! How could this be fixed?

My Form:

```
class TestForm(Form):
    testpedio = StringField('Testpedio', [validators.Length(min=1, max=200)])
    erga = SelectField('ergo',  choices=[])
```

My Code:

```
@app.route('/add_test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@is_logged_in
def add_test():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ergo FROM erga")
    list1 = list(cur.fetchall())
    def arx():
        for i in list1:
            for k in i:
                j=i[k]
                list2.append(j)

    list2=[]
    arx()
    print(list2)

    form = TestForm(request.form)
    form.erga.choices= [(i,i) for i in list2]
    print(form.erga.choices)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        testpedio = form.testpedio.data

        # Create Cursor
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

        # Execute
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(testpedio,ergo,author) VALUES(%s,%s, %s)",(testpedio,erga,session['username']))

        # Commit to DB
        mysql.connection.commit()

        #Close connection
        cur.close()

        flash('Test Created', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('add_test.html', form=form)
```

The page with the `SelectField` that shows that everything works as intended:
[image: Form]
[image]

The Table
[image: MySQL Table]

Comment: Do you happen to have a function that is called `erga`? Also, please try `erga` in `cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(testpedio,ergo,author) VALUES(%s,%s, %s)",(testpedio,erga,session['username']))` with `form.erga.data`. Using `dict(form.erga.choices).get(form.erga.data)` will also hopefully do the job, if you want to specifically get the value. `form.erga.data` will suffice, basing from your code.

Comment: So, your execution statement will look like `cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(testpedio,ergo,author) VALUES(%s,%s, %s)",(testpedio,form.erga.data,session['username']))`.

Comment: From the information we can gather from your question, the cause as to why your app is inserting functions (though it seems that it is actually inserting the value of `__repr__` and not the function itself) is probably because you defined `erga` to be a function somewhere in your code.

Comment: exactly! I had a function called erga above in my code... Thx a lot, problem solved :)

Comment: Glad that helped! I'll be putting my comment up as my answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function that is called `erga` somewhere in your code. That is the reason why you are inserting functions instead of values. To fix your code, you will want to change your execution statement from:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(testpedio,ergo,author) VALUES(%s,%s, %s)",(testpedio,erga,session['username']))
```

to:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test(testpedio,ergo,author) VALUES(%s,%s, %s)",(testpedio,form.erga.data,session['username']))
```

Note that we changed `erga` in the execution statement to `form.erga.data` so that we will get the value of the `SelectField` in your form. It is important to know that `form.erga.data` will give you the key of the choice you selected. In your case, we do not need to worry about that since the key and value of your selection options are the same. However, in future cases, the key may be different. So, in those cases, to get the actual values of the selection options, you might want to use `dict(form.erga.choices).get(form.erga.data)` instead.